# Shell mode in Inkscape 1.0

Tags: inkscape

I used to have a list of commands in a text file like this:

```
-f ./input1.svg -e ../output1.png -y 0 -w 72
-f ./input2.svg -e ../output2.png -y 0 -w 240
```

and used to run `inkscape --shell < commands.txt`.

But I cant figure out how to do that in Inkscape 1.0!

Comment: Inkscape 1.0 isn't released yet, you are probably referring to 1.0 beta1 or the current development version.

Find instructions for the new command line here: https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Command_Line - and let us know if you figure out how to use it... Here's a possibly related bug report: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/issues/428

Comment: (maybe join the developer chat and try to get hold of one of Tav, ede123 or Mc - they are most likely to know how/if it works)

Comment: yea dev chat might be an option. the gitlab issue is actually from me:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the release of Inkscape 1.0, one can now do it this way:

```
echo "file-open:$INPUT_FILEPATH/$INPUT_FILENAME; export-filename:$DESTINATION; export-width:$NEW_RES; export-do" >> commands.txt

# Repeat above for each file

echo "quit" >> commands.txt

inkscape --shell < commands.txt
rm -f ./commands.txt
```

Comment: Is anyone able to make this work correctly on the Windows command line instead of Linux?

Answer (score 1):

To just make it work again (not using the --shell mode), you could handle reading your `commands.txt` outside of inkscape and pass single commands to it. If you use xargs, you could run it even in parallel.

Assumming you have a commands.txt with all arguments in one line per input file, like

```
--export-filename=test72.png --export-width=72 input.svg
--export-filename=test36.png --export-width=36 input.svg
```

you could execute them as a batch like this:

```
cat commands.txt | xargs -P2 -L1 inkscape
```

`-P<number>` optional: is the amount of threads you want to run in parallel (using not more than you have cpu cores in your device available is reasonable)

`-L1` specifies how many non-empty lines of your input file are passed as arguments to inkscape

Comment: This is fine, but it calls inkscape once for each line, as opposed to calling the inkscape executable with a list of files to convert. If you want to convert many files your approach will be significantly slower. Passing a batch file with a series of commands to inkscape in --shell mode seems to work well in Linux but I have had issues in Windows. Hopefully those issues will be resolved soon.

Comment: Yes, totally agree, its slow and reinitializes inkscape all the time and for that reason eats up the parallelization effect to a fair amount. I meant it more in a way to ad-hoc fix it (and throw as many hardware on it as available) and get away with that hopefully before improving further. If I remember right, Inkscape had quite some shifts in their API with releasing 1.0 there and it seemed that some features are still to come a little later and then allowing a nicer solution.